# AES to return Alphanumeric

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I have an aes encryption code, i want to make it only return alphanumerical characters like `{0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTWUVYZ}`

But however i could not figure out how to do that. I have almost no idea about encryption, could not figure out where to fix. I would really apreciate your feedback. Regards...

```
public class clsCrypto
    {
        private string _KEY = string.Empty;
        protected internal string KEY
        {
            get
            {
                return _KEY;
            }
            set
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                {
                    _KEY = value;
                }
            }
        }

        private string _IV = string.Empty;
        protected internal string IV
        {
            get
            {
                return _IV;
            }
            set
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                {
                    _IV = value;
                }
            }
        }

        private string CalcMD5(string strInput)
        {
            string strOutput = string.Empty;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strInput))
            {
                try
                {
                    StringBuilder strHex = new StringBuilder();
                    using (MD5 md5 = MD5.Create())
                    {
                        byte[] bytArText = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(strInput);
                        byte[] bytArHash = md5.ComputeHash(bytArText);
                        for (int i = 0; i < bytArHash.Length; i++)
                        {
                            strHex.Append(bytArHash[i].ToString("X2"));
                        }
                        strOutput = strHex.ToString();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
            return strOutput;
        }

        private byte[] GetBytesFromHexString(string strInput)
        {
            byte[] bytArOutput = new byte[] { };
            if ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strInput)) && strInput.Length % 2 == 0)
            {
                SoapHexBinary hexBinary = null;
                try
                {
                    hexBinary = SoapHexBinary.Parse(strInput);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
                bytArOutput = hexBinary.Value;
            }
            return bytArOutput;
        }

        private byte[] GenerateIV()
        {
            byte[] bytArOutput = new byte[] { };
            try
            {
                string strIV = CalcMD5(IV);
                bytArOutput = GetBytesFromHexString(strIV);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            return bytArOutput;
        }

        private byte[] GenerateKey()
        {
            byte[] bytArOutput = new byte[] { };
            try
            {
                string strKey = CalcMD5(KEY);
                bytArOutput = GetBytesFromHexString(strKey);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            return bytArOutput;
        }

        protected internal string Encrypt(string strInput, CipherMode cipherMode)
        {
            string strOutput = string.Empty;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strInput))
            {
                try
                {
                    byte[] bytePlainText = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(strInput);
                    using (RijndaelManaged rijManaged = new RijndaelManaged())
                    {
                        rijManaged.Mode = cipherMode;
                        rijManaged.BlockSize = 128;
                        rijManaged.KeySize = 128;
                        rijManaged.IV = GenerateIV();
                        rijManaged.Key = GenerateKey();
                        rijManaged.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
                        ICryptoTransform icpoTransform = rijManaged.CreateEncryptor(rijManaged.Key, rijManaged.IV);
                        using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            using (CryptoStream cpoStream = new CryptoStream(memStream, icpoTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                            {
                                cpoStream.Write(bytePlainText, 0, bytePlainText.Length);
                                cpoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                            }
                            strOutput = Encoding.Default.GetString(memStream.ToArray());
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
            return strOutput;
        }

        protected internal string Decrypt(string strInput, CipherMode cipherMode)
        {
            string strOutput = string.Empty;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strInput))
            {
                try
                {
                    byte[] byteCipherText = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(strInput);
                    byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[strInput.Length];
                    using (RijndaelManaged rijManaged = new RijndaelManaged())
                    {
                        rijManaged.Mode = cipherMode;
                        rijManaged.BlockSize = 128;
                        rijManaged.KeySize = 128;
                        rijManaged.IV = GenerateIV();
                        rijManaged.Key = GenerateKey();
                        rijManaged.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
                        ICryptoTransform icpoTransform = rijManaged.CreateDecryptor(rijManaged.Key, rijManaged.IV);
                        using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(byteCipherText))
                        {
                            using (CryptoStream cpoStream = new CryptoStream(memStream, icpoTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                            {
                                cpoStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, byteBuffer.Length);
                            }
                            strOutput = Encoding.Default.GetString(byteBuffer);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
            return strOutput;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Encryption and decryption functions use byte arrays as parameters.
So, you must convert these arrays to base 36 string.

You can use the following class (Base36) to make these conversions:

All you have to do, is calling these two functions:

```
 byte[] byteArray;

 //To convert byte array to String 
 string byteArrayInBase36 = Base36.ByteArrayToBase36String(byteArray);

 //To convert String to byte Array
 byte[] byteArray2 = Base36.Base36StringToByteArray(byteArrayInBase36);
```

and, this is the class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Base36
{
#region public methods
public static string ByteArrayToBase36String(byte[] bytes)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    result = Encode36((ulong)bytes.Length).PadLeft(BASE36_LENGTH_BLOC_SIZE_36, '0');

    if (bytes.Length > 0)
    {
        List<byte[]> byteslist = SplitBytes(bytes, 8);
        if (byteslist[byteslist.Count - 1].Length < 8)
        {
            byte[] newLastArray = new byte[8];
            byteslist[byteslist.Count - 1].CopyTo(newLastArray, 0);
            byteslist[byteslist.Count - 1] = newLastArray;
        }
        foreach (byte[] byteArray in byteslist)
        {
            ulong value = 0;

            //for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.Length; i++) value = value * 256 + byteArray[i];
            value = BitConverter.ToUInt64(byteArray, 0);
            result = result + Encode36(value).PadLeft(BASE36_BLOC_SIZE_36, '0');
        }
    }
    return result;
}
public static byte[] Base36StringToByteArray(string input)
{
    byte[] result = new byte[0];
    if (input.Length >= BASE36_LENGTH_BLOC_SIZE_36)
    {
        int arrayLength = (int)Decode36(input.Substring(0, BASE36_LENGTH_BLOC_SIZE_36));
        string data = input.Remove(0, BASE36_LENGTH_BLOC_SIZE_36);
        List<byte[]> bytesList = new List<byte[]>();
        foreach (string value36 in new List<string>(SplitStringByLength(data, BASE36_BLOC_SIZE_36)))
        {
            byte[] byteArray = BitConverter.GetBytes(Decode36(value36));
            bytesList.Add(byteArray);
        }
        result = JoinBytes(bytesList);
        Array.Resize(ref result, arrayLength);
    }
    return result;
}
#endregion

#region Const
private const int BASE36_LENGTH_BLOC_SIZE_36 = 6;
private const int BASE36_BLOC_SIZE_36 = 13; //Encode36(ulong.MaxValue).Length;
#endregion

#region private methods
static string _CharList36 = string.Empty;
static private string CharList36
{
    get
    {
        if (_CharList36.Length < 36)
        {
            char[] array = new char[36];
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) array[i] = (char)(i + 48);
            for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) array[i + 10] = (char)(i + 97);
            _CharList36 = new string(array);
        }
        return _CharList36;
    }
}

private static List<string> SplitStringByLength(string str, int chunkSize)
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < str.Length / chunkSize; i++)
    {
        list.Add(str.Substring(i * chunkSize, chunkSize));
    }
    i = i * chunkSize;
    if (i < str.Length - 1)
        list.Add(str.Substring(i, str.Length - i));
    return list;
}

private static String Encode36(ulong input)
{
    if (input < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("input", input, "input cannot be negative");

    char[] clistarr = CharList36.ToCharArray();
    var result = new Stack<char>();
    while (input != 0)
    {
        result.Push(clistarr[input % 36]);
        input /= 36;
    }
    return new string(result.ToArray()).ToUpper();
}

private static ulong Decode36(string input)
{
    var reversed = ReverseString(input.ToLower());
    ulong result = 0;
    int pos = 0;
    foreach (char c in reversed)
    {
        result += (ulong)CharList36.IndexOf(c) * (ulong)Math.Pow(36, pos);
        pos++;
    }
    return result;
}

private static string ReverseString(string text)
{
    char[] cArray = text.ToCharArray();
    string reverse = String.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < cArray.Length / 2; i++)
    {
        char c = cArray[i];
        cArray[i] = cArray[cArray.Length - 1 - i];
        cArray[cArray.Length - 1 - i] = c;
    }
    return new string(cArray);
}

private static byte[] StringToBytes(string str)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    return bytes;
}

private static List<byte[]> SplitBytes(byte[] bytes, int length)
{
    List<byte[]> result = new List<byte[]>();

    int position = 0;
    while (bytes.Length - position > length)
    {
        byte[] temp = new byte[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.Length; i++) temp[i] = bytes[i + position];
        position += length;
        result.Add(temp);
    }
    if (position < bytes.Length)
    {
        byte[] temp = new byte[bytes.Length - position];
        for (int i = 0; i + position < bytes.Length; i++) temp[i] = bytes[i + position];
        result.Add(temp);
    }
    return result;
}

private static string BytesToString(byte[] bytes)
{
    char[] chars = new char[bytes.Length / sizeof(char)];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, chars, 0, bytes.Length);
    return new string(chars);
}

private static byte[] JoinBytes(List<byte[]> listBytes)
{
    int totalLength = 0;
    foreach (byte[] bytes in listBytes) totalLength += bytes.Length;
    byte[] result = new byte[totalLength];
    int position = 0;
    foreach (byte[] bytes in listBytes)
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
        {
            result[position] = bytes[i];
            position++;
        }
    return result;
}

#endregion
}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked well! :)
By the way,     
private static string Base36ToString(string input)
    {
        return BytesToString(Base36ToByteArray(input));
    }

    private static string StringToBase36(string input)
    {
        return ByteArrayToBase36(StringToBytes(input));
    }

gave error but code works well enough without them :)

Answer (score 1):

You can encode the resulting bytes using [Base36](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_36) or another such [binary-to-text encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding).