# encrypting username in asp.net mvc5 login

Tags: c#, encryption, forms-authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I want to encrypt the username for the login of an asp.net mvc5 site. When the controller calls `var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user,model.Password);` to register a new user, I get an error telling me

> User name abc/12&3== is invalid, can only contain letters or digits.

I'm guessing I cannot make this function take these non-alphanumeric values, so how can I make an AES encrypted value fall within the guidelines?

Thanks, Dave K.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have found a way to hack around this but the real problem is just that you need to change the user validator:

```
UserManager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(UserManager) 
  {
    AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
  };
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  What is the reasoning this is not set to false by default, does it impose some sort of penalty, whether that is performance, security or other?

Comment: I suppose the risk is that you could do things like go inserting non-breaking spaces into usernames and impersonating other users.

Answer (score 1):

Found something that worked on another post, converted the value to a [Base36](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17855071/aes-to-return-alphanumeric)

Comment: You could have done this without making that change.